# Finding a specific function

Tags: functions

I would like to construct a function where:

- $A(1) = 0$
- $A:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0, \infty)$
- A is bijective
- $A(a)A(b) = A(a + b)$

The only function that I've found that comes close to this would be power functions such as $2^x$ as $2^a 2^b = 2^{a+b}$.

Comment: Maybe you want $A(0)=1$, otherwise $0=0^2=A(1)A(1)=A(2)$, and $A$ is not injective.

Comment: If it is what Crostul says, then yes: exponential functions work just fine.

Comment: In fact if $A(1)=0$, then $A(x)=A(1)A(x-1)=0A(x-1)=0$ for all $x$, which is not very interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such function. In fact, suppose such function $A$ exists. Then, by bijectivity of $A$, there exists some $s \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $A(s)=0$.

Now, $$A(s)=0=0 \cdot A(1) = A(s)A(1) = A(s+1)$$
and this contradicts bijectivity.